# Multiples array - Call in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to call the value from my array but i have a problem. When its on only one level, i arrive there. But when he have 2 or 3 level, i can't.

This is my array.

```
    [
    {
    "total": "4",
    "nbPage": 10,
    "color": {
        "reference": "56f50a7e4fhghc8c",
        "name": "Noir"
    },
    "gallery": [
        {
            "thumb": "exemple.png",
            "position": 0,
            "reference": "cfc84f0752adc96b489sdf71195d91a946c5f6d3e8",
            "updatedAt": "2017-06-08T10:04:23+0200"
        }
    ],
```

With this function for example, i arrive to call the first point:

```
<?php echo $vehicules[0]->reference; ?>
```

But to call, for example "Color & Reference" i dont find solution. I search on a lot of topic about this subject, but i'm on the same step 2 hours later.. **Thanks you !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an object within an array, and are looking for:

```
$vehicules[0]->color // To access the colour object
$vehicules[0]->color->reference // To access the colour reference (56f50a7e4fhghc8c)
```

To access the gallery reference, you would use:

```
$vehicules[0]->gallery[0]->reference // cfc84f0752adc96b489sdf71195d91a946c5f6d3e8
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks you very much ! 